# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS : sky2 ethernet stops working after system resume from suspend?

Tags: drivers, lts, 18.04

I upgraded Ubuntu 17.10 to version 18.04 LTS .... and unfortunately I encountered a problem with the network card / driver: sky2

```
sky2 ethernet stops working after system resume from suspend !
```

I returned again from backup to version 17.10 .....

but I checked a few releases of Ubuntu LTS for example Xubuntu 18.04 / Lubuntu 18.04 / mod Voyager LTS 18.04 in LIVE version
Everywhere this error occurs:

> sky2 ethernet stops working after system resume from suspend !

help trick / script / entry in the terminal:

```
..........................

sleep 5
case $1/$2 in
post/*)
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
modprobe -r sky2
modprobe sky2
;;
esac

chmod +x !

..................................
```

this is probably related to the kernel version on Ubuntu 17.10 is: 4.13.0-39
on version LTS 18.04 kernel 4.15.0-20

```
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Yukon Optima 88E8059 [PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Controller with AVB] [11ab:4381] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Yukon Optima 88E8059 [PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Controller with AVB] [144d:c06a]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 24
    Region 0: Memory at f5420000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Region 2: I/O ports at b000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at f5400000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sky2
    Kernel modules: sky2
```

Comment: will there be a patch like kernel or do I need to use this script fix?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is discussed on the bug reporter at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1758507

According to the thread, a solution should be coming soon. :)

Answer (score -1):

OK ...problem solved
I checked dmesg .....error:
[ 380.567633] do_**IRQ: 3.34 No irq handler for vector**

I applied fix to grub file : pci=nomsi,noaer

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi,noaer"
```

update-grub / reboot
and everything works fine ??? :-)

Comment: or  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash sky2.disable_msi=1"